# Как они это сделали? огромная задержка при парсинге страниц

Tags: php, curl, wget

если гуляем по сайту через браузер, например откроем эту страницу

https:/xxxxxxx/product/fd751eba62c73330/surupovert-patriot-the-one-br-141/

сайт реагирует довольно быстро

Но если эту же страницу мы запросим например через консоль wget

```
wget https://xxxxxx/product/fd751eba62c73330/surupovert-patriot-the-one-br-141/
```

то она скачаетсягде то через 25-30 секунд.

как такое реализовать и как можно это обойти? наверно все дело в заголовках?

делал так

```
wget --referer=https://www.xxxx --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0" https://www.xxxxx
```

не помогло, 21 секунду получает страничку! скорость 9кбит) вот каккк как они это сделали???

Comment: Если вы посмотрите на индикатор загрузки страницы, он довольно долго висит. Т.е. первоначально сервер быстро отдает страницу, и потом на странице выполняются скрипты для отложенной загрузки данных (подгрузка картинок и т.п.).

Comment: причем тут индикатор, запрашиваем же просто тело страницы, wget не браузер, он не выполняю скриптов

Comment: refer & user agent.

Comment: добавил в вопрос, не помогло, делал так http://prntscr.com/kats5z = 21 секунда

Comment: запрашиваю также гугл - отвечает мгновенно 9 мс

Comment: делаю курлом. за 3 с половиной секунды отрабатывает

Comment: хз делал курлом, также долго, ну и видно как он порциями отдает контент, блоками, также не должно быть, видно что порезана скорость сильно.

Comment: если что Accept-Encoding: gzip - решил проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вся проблема была в заголовке, стоило мне добавить в запрос заголовок:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

данные стали прилетать быстро, но их потребовалось расшифровывать) но это полбеды, зато победил ужасно низкую скорость отдачи данных!